# Is lat? a primitive function in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

Suppose l is defined as follows:

```
> (define l (list 1 2 3))
```

l is now bound to a list of atoms.

Little Schemer introduces a simple function called lat? which evaluates to #t or #f depending on the argument's classification as a list of atoms. For instance,

```
> (lat? l)
```

should evaluate to #t, since l is a list of three atoms.

However, my scheme interpreter ([repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/scheme)) throws an error when asked to call lat?.

```
> (lat? l)
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "lat" []
```

Am I wrong in assuming lat? is primitive to Scheme?

Also, please excuse a repost be that the case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

lat? is defined early on in the book. See page 19.

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) #t)
      ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l)))
      (else #f))))
```

The book specifies what a function needs to do and what outputs it needs to generate in a conversational way that may take getting used to.

Comment: Yup. Included the definition in my answer. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is a silly question: the text tasks the reader with devising a definition. Here's the answer in case anyone is interested:

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) #t)
      ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l))
      (else #f))))
```